# How can I update a variable to keep track of the current value minus the previous value in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, text-files

Say I have a text file that has the following data:

```
9.079929479691208
12.97415710230641
29.298703770316134
27.948996122147257
22.226701761850222
24.87655187612297
34.411572810292476
```

if the name of the file is text.txt, I've tried doing this but it won't work:

```
previous_val = 0
current_val = 0
file = open("text.txt","r")
for line in file:
    line = line.strip()
    rows = line.split(" ")
    values = float(rows[0])
    current_val = float(values - previous_val)
    print(current_val)
```

the first value should stay the same as 9.079... because there was nothing before it, but the next one should be 3.whatver because 12.974... - 9.079... = 3.whatever. It should keep doing that the whole way through. When I run the program, it just returns the exact same numbers that are in the text file. If someone could please help me with this I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: You don't want the fraction part?

Comment: @AhsanulHaque Yes I would want the whole number. Doesn't matter if it's a fraction

Comment: As you forgot to assign a value to `previous_val` in your loop; it always remains 0 which is why you are just getting the same output as the file.

Comment: When you say keep doing that, is the next value 25.4 (29.29 - 3.89) or 16.32 (29.29 - 12.97), if the latter please ignore my answer, I read it as the former.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `previous_val` in every iteration. Look at this:

```
previous_val = 0
file = open("text.txt","r")
for line in file:
    current = float(line.strip())
    print current - previous_val
    previous_val = current
```

Output:

```
9.07992947969
3.89422762262
16.324546668
-1.34970764817
-5.7222943603
2.64985011427
9.53502093417
```

Answer (score 1):

You never change the value of `previous_val` after assigning it a value of zero, so `current_val = float(values - previous_val)` is equivalent to `current_val = float(values)`

You want:

```
current_val, previous_val = float(values - previous_val), current_val
```

This assigns `current_val` to the difference and `previous_val` to the preceding `current_val`.

Answer (score 1):

```
previous_val = 0
current_val = 0
file = open("text.txt","r")
for line in file:
    line = line.strip()  
    #rows = line.split(" ") # no need to split
    values = float(line)
    current_val = float(values - previous_val)
    print(current_val)
    previous_val = float(line)
```

Comment: You can't confidently say no strip is needed. What about some white spaces?

Answer (score 0):

In python3 you can use [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=count#itertools.accumulate) to do want you want:

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> with open("text.txt","r") as file:
...     list(accumulate((float(line.strip()) for line in file), lambda a, b: b-a))
[9.079929479691208,
 3.894227622615203,
 25.404476147700933,
 2.544519974446324,
 19.6821817874039,
 5.194370088719072,
 29.217202721573404]
```

It is pretty easy to implement accumulate, and a reference implementation is provided in the documentation